# Solving simultaneous trigonometric equations

Tags: equation-solving, trigonometry

Is it possible to solve these equations together ? PS:I am new to Mathematica
[image: Here are the equations]

The only unknowns are theta 1 and alpha 1 , you can consider the rest constants
I am using this

```
Reduce[{
   y == ArcTan[(3000 - 30*Sin[2 x + 0.0093] - 30^2/(4*3000))/(30 + 
       30 Cos[2 x + 0.0093]), 
   x == (Pi/2 - 0.0093 - y)/2]
}, {x, y}]
```

but it returns an error requiring exact values

Comment: Is a1 same as alpha1 ?

Comment: yes it is , sorry for that

Comment: There was a syntax issue with your code. Also, FindRoot is best if you are ok with numerical results. FindRoot[{y == 
   ArcTan[(3000 - 30*Sin[2 x + 0.0093] - 30^2/(4*3000))/(30 + 
       30 Cos[2 x + 0.0093])], 
  x == (Pi/2 - 0.0093 - y)/2}, {{x, 1}, {y, 1}}]

Comment: Thank you for the answer !  I just forgot to copy that syntax error fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the equations can be solved in MMA.  Equation solving is an advanced subject.  Here is one approach for solving the equations:

```
eqn = Tan[θ] == (f - r Sin[π/2 - θ] - z)/(x + r Cos[π/2 - θ])
    eqn = eqn /. α -> (π/2 - θ - ω)/2
    eqn = eqn /. f -> g + z
    soln = Solve[eqn, θ] // Simplify

    (*  {{θ -> ConditionalExpression[
    ArcTan[(g*r - Sqrt[x^2*(g^2 - r^2 + x^2)])/(g^2 + x^2), 
      -((r*x^2 + g*Sqrt[x^2*(g^2 - r^2 + x^2)])/
       (g^2*x + x^3))] + 2*Pi*C[1], 
    Element[C[1], Integers]]}, 
 {θ -> ConditionalExpression[
    ArcTan[(g*r + Sqrt[x^2*(g^2 - r^2 + x^2)])/(g^2 + x^2), 
      -((r*x^2 - g*Sqrt[x^2*(g^2 - r^2 + x^2)])/
       (g^2*x + x^3))] + 2*Pi*C[1], 
    Element[C[1], Integers]]}}  *)
```

Explanation:  In the first line we write our equation.  Note the use of single = and double == signs.  In the second line we replace all of $\alpha$'s with the expression we have.  In the third line we replace the variable $f$ with $g+z$.  In the fourth line, we solve for $\theta$.

Where did $g$ come from?  First, we solved the equation without $g$ and got an even more complicated expression.  We recognized that $f^2-2fz+z^2$ appeared several places in the solution and thought it would be simpler to write that part as some $g^2$.  So, we tried it and it worked -- we did get a simpler expression.  Try it without the third step and see which one you prefer.

We got 2 different expressions for the solution and each on them involves an arbitrary constant, `C[1]`, which must be an integer.  So there are an infinite number of solutions.

MMA has put the solution in terms of an arctangent function with 2 arguments.  Those two arguments are $x, y$, not $y, x$.

Comment: This `(π/2 - θ - ω)` should be `(π/2 - θ - ω)/2`?

Comment: @zhk  Thank you!  I have updated the code and the MMA solution.  Good catch, Z.